# How to create a loop that executes from first month of last year to current month in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a while loop in sql server which starts execution from January, 2014 and executes until current month of current year.

This is my code right now,

```
declare @month int
set @month = 1
while @month <= 12
 begin
  truncate table #temp_Products
  insert into #temp_Products
  exec sp_Products_Count_Monthly @month, @year
  insert into temp_Products_monthly
  select @month as Created_Month, @year as Created_Year, * from #temp_Products
  set @month = @month + 1
 end
```

I know loops are not a good practice in SQL, but I do not know how to execute a stored procedure for each month and store the result set in a table.

So I want to get the results from January 2014 until current month of 2015.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loops aren't the best performing solution, at least in all cases, but if you can divide your work into smaller pieces (but not into row-by-row processing) it might actually be better than trying to do a really complex thing to handle everything at once.

For this you could just use a simple date variable for the loop:

```
declare @tmpdate date, @year int, @month int
set @tmpdate = '20140101'
while @tmpdate < getdate() begin
  set @month = month(@tmpdate)
  set @year = year(@tmpdate)

  truncate table #temp_Products

  insert into #temp_Products
  exec sp_Products_Count_Monthly @month, @year

  insert into temp_Products_monthly
  select @month as Created_Month, @year as Created_Year, * from #temp_Products

  set @tmpdate = dateadd(month, 1, @tmpdate)
end
```

If this is executed a lot, then you probably should try to rewrite the whole logic, so that you wouldn't need to call a separate procedure for each month, but actually fetch the whole data in single batch.

Comment: In the exec sp_Products_Count_Monthly line, it will be month, year, right? instead of @tmpdate